# jQuery is returning 0 for a div's height

Tags: jquery

I've looked at all the related questions and cannot find the solution to my problem in IE, works fine in all other browers but not IE.  The issue is with jQuery I'm always getting 0 when I try and get the height with the function .height().  Here is a link to the page: http://prayersphere.com/acraig/

Comment: Have you tried innerHeight?

Comment: Can you show your html and jquery code?

Comment: I have a link that is the example I'm working with.

Comment: Try something like `<div style="float: left; clear: both;"></div>` at the bottom of that div. A [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try :
`$(window).height()` instead of `.height()` ?

Comment: ha, yes! that is working, now I just need to figure out why the height of the menu isn't working on IE in css then I'll be good.

Comment: You could try this if you are not already trying it 
$("#yourmenu").css({"height":"--px","width":"--px"});

Comment: Can you accept this as your answer if you have nailed your problem , else are you still facing issues?

Comment: yes this will work, but just cannot nail down why the menu div will not get measured correctly, but yes since I want the height to be 100% window will work just as well.